# DVC print data version -git tag of the current data file_using python API

Tags: python, git, version, dvc

I am currently using DVC to track my data and am usually adding the git tag to version the data file, I am manually checking out to particular version of the data. Is there a way to print the data version inside a python code.

I have tried using `dvc.api.exp_show()`
but it gets me all the list;
also tried
`dvc.api.all_tags`,
same!

But, I want to print the current version of the data.

Comment: `I am manually checking out to particular version of the data. `  - could you clarify please - what does it actually mean?

Comment: @Shcheklein I usually tag the data version with git tag and when i am set on using particular version of data, i do 'git checkout tag_name(version) data.dvc' and then dvc checkout data.dvc. However i want to print the version of data inside python.